# How to scatter shapes without overlapping while keeping them close together?

Tags: javascript, statistics, processing, p5.js

here's something I have been trying to figure out but couldn't because I suck at math or statistics :S

There are a lot of ways to scatter i.e. a bunch of divs or a p5 canvas element (sized slightly differently) without them overlapping - [this](http://youtube.com/watch?v=XATr_jdh-44&feature=youtu.be) is an example of doing it with circles. But if the total number of those elements is low, then there’s a chance that the cluster will be very far apart from each other, and the overall density can be quite inconsitent. Is there a way to scatter similarly sized rectangles without overlapping and remains a minimum distance from each other, but is never too far away?

**Ideally something like this:**

[image]

**And not this (which is the outcome if the only criteria is "no overlapping"):**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could translate to the centre before drawing the shapes and then give them a distance from the centre using the random function where the max value for random will be calculated according to the total number of elements. While doing this, you may also check for overlapping and call the random function again if any two objects overlap.